# Converting my project to a package with modules

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

I am converting my python project into packages, with sub-packages, with modules. The tree structure is as shown below (sorry for the long tree). When I run `run.py`, it imports `MyEnvironment.environment` which in turn has statements like `from station import Station`. It is at this stage that I get an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'station'`. I am not able to figure why this is happening. Note that it work when I do `sys.append('.\Environment')`, but it should work without it since I already added `__init__.py`. Could someone help here?

````
C:.
├───.vscode
│       settings.json
│
└───DRLOD-Package
    │   run.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───MyEnvironment
    │   │   agv.py
    │   │   environment.py
    │   │   job.py
    │   │   job_queue.py
    │   │   parent_area.py
    │   │   path_finding.py
    │   │   pdnode.py
    │   │   policy.py
    │   │   request.py
    │   │   station.py
    │   │   stats.py
    │   │   test.py
    │   │   __init__.py
    ```
````

Comment: In `environment.py` use `from .station import Station`.

Comment: Off-topic: FWIW, you should avoid putting `'-'` (dash) characters in module and package names because that character is not valid in Python identifiers — I suggest using `'_'` (underscore) characters instead.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain, what happens by adding '.' ?

Comment: It means relative to the current directory (just like it does in OS file/directory paths). Lookup Python "relative imports".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In environment.py use from .station import Station